# c++ winsock server-client remote connection

Tags: c++, winsock

I am trying to create a simple app that exchanges messages between two remote computers.
With the "127.0.0.1" ip it works properly, waits for the client's confirm and connects to the client, but if I try a local "192.168.0.15" or my global ip with the same port, the server connects immediately to sth without waiting for the client.

Here's part of my server code:

```
char ip[20] = "127.0.0.1"; int port = 19385;

SOCKET sockListen, sockConnect;

SOCKADDR_IN address;

sockConnect = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr (ip);
address.sin_family = AF_INET;
address.sin_port = htons (port); 
sockListen = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);

bind (sockListen, (SOCKADDR*)&address, AddressSize);
listen (sockListen, SOMAXCONN);

sockConnect = accept (sockListen, (SOCKADDR*)&address, &AddressSize);
```

...

Please suggest how to fix the problem. thx

Comment: Why don't you try using boost.Asio. You will save your self a lot of headache.

Comment: Shouldn't the line `sockConnect = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);` initialise `sockListen` instead of `sockClient`?

Comment: sockListen is also initialized below. the order doesn't matter

Comment: @Caesar my guess is because he wants to use winsock. Just because there is a library to do something doesn't mean you should use it. Having an understanding of the native API goes a long way.

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to initialize your `sockConnect` variable with `socket()` before calling `accept()`.  `accept()` returns a **new** allocated socket handle that is already connected to a client.  You are leaking the socket handle that `socket()` allocated.

You can only `bind()` to an IP that belongs to a NIC of the local machine that the app is running on. You cannot `bind()` to an external IP.

The code you have shown is not doing any error handling at all.  You need to add that, eg:

```
int errCode;

SOCKET sockListen = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL); 
if (sockListen == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    errCode = WSAGetLastError();
    // ...
}
else
{ 
    SOCKADDR_IN address = {0}; 
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr (ip); 
    address.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    address.sin_port = htons (port);  

    if (bind (sockListen, (SOCKADDR*)&address, sizeof(address)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        errCode = WSAGetLastError();
        // ...
    }
    else
    {
        if (listen (sockListen, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            errCode = WSAGetLastError();
            // ...
        }
        else
        {
            int addressSize; 

            SOCKET sockClient = accept (sockListen, (SOCKADDR*)&address, &addressSize); 
            if (sockClient == INVALID_SOCKET)
            {
                errCode = WSAGetLastError();
                // ...
            }
            else
            {
                // ...
                closesocket(sockClient);
            }
        }
    }

    closesocket(sockListen);
}
```